# in C++, get an error says "std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' is not derived from 'const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>"

Tags: c++

```
int webServerPort = -1;    

void configure(std::string responseFile, callback_function call_back, std::string urlRegex = NULL) {
        std::string url = "http://0.0.0.0:" + webServerPort + "fake_settings/?file=" + responseFile;
        if(urlRegex != NULL) {  // GOT ERROR HERE
            url += "&pattern=" + urlRegex;
        }
```

Get an error, in fact it is not called as "error" but "note"

Error says: note:   'std::string {aka std::basic_string}' is not derived from 'const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>'

anyone get any idea about it?

Thanks

Comment: Trying changing `std::string urlRegex = NULL` to `std::string urlRegex = ""` and `if(urlRegex != NULL)` to `if(!urlRegex.empty())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things: Firstly you're defaulting `urlRegex` to `NULL`. Did you mean this to be empty string? If so, don't bother as that's the default for a string anyway. Then when you check for `urlRegex` being NULL, instead do:

```
if(!urlRegex.empty()) { // ...
```

Secondly, you're trying to add `webServerPort` (an int) onto a std::string. That's not legal. If you really want to do this then the way to go about it would be:

```
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << "http://0.0.0.0:" << webServerPort << "fake_settings/?file=" << responseFile;
std::string url = ss.str();
```